# How to link css

Tags: vraptor

I am new to web design and am having some problems , one of them (which is killing me ) is that I can not link the css my JSP page . My problem is " simple " : 404 NOT FOUND in the css file.

Actually I got the code below :
 < % @ include file = " ../../ css / bootstrap.min.css " % > < / style>
However , the q I understand , this is a code that means " brute force " pq copy all css to the HTML page .

I've tried the following methods :

```
- < Link href = " $ { } pageContext.request.contextPath /css/teste.css " rel = "stylesheet " type = "text / css " >

- < % @ Taglib prefix = " fmt " uri = " http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt " % >
< % @ Taglib prefix = " c " uri = " http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core " % >
...
<link href = " < c : url value = " / css / teste.css " / > " rel = "stylesheet " >
```

Comment: yes,I thought it'd be nice to use new front end stuff with v raptor

Comment: I see a lot of people having problems with css3 and vraptor,I'm not sure if there is a real connection between that but it's nice to investigate that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a folder inside webapps and call it resource you create folders for your css , js or images .
To use, simply do:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<c:url value="/resources/css/yourfile.css"/>">
```